# How to Sort json by date range using jquery?

Tags: jquery, sorting

I have one date range json and my json is unsorted so my date range is not come correct order.I have try 2 solution but not getting correct result.

Here Below This is json:

```
0: { Status : 1
 DateFrom : "2018-09-01 00:00" 
 DateTo : "2018-09-08 00:00" }
1: { Status : 1
 DateFrom : "2018-09-02 00:00" 
 DateTo : "2018-09-08 00:00" }
2: { Status : 1
 DateFrom : "2018-09-08 00:00" 
 DateTo : "2018-09-15 00:00" }
3: { Status : 1
 DateFrom : "2018-10-01 00:00" 
 DateTo : "2018-10-06 00:00" }
4: { Status : 1
 DateFrom : "2018-10-06 00:00" 
 DateTo : "2018-10-13 00:00" }
5: { Status : 1
 DateFrom : "2018-07-01 00:00" 
 DateTo : "2018-07-07 00:00" }
6: { Status : 1
 DateFrom : "2018-07-07 00:00" 
 DateTo : "2018-07-14 00:00" }
7: { Status : 1
 DateFrom : "2018-08-04 00:00" 
 DateTo : "2018-08-11 00:00" }
```

I have try below code with but not getting correct result.

```
var res = JSON.parse($("#hdfAvailabe").val());

//This one try
res.sort(function (left, right) {
return moment.utc(left.timeStamp).diff(moment.utc(right.timeStamp))
});

//This second try
res.sort(function (a, b) {
return a - b
})
```

This is my excepted output:

```
0: { Status : 1
 DateFrom : "2018-07-01 00:00" 
 DateTo : "2018-07-07 00:00" }
 1: { Status : 1
 DateFrom : "2018-07-07 00:00" 
 DateTo : "2018-07-14 00:00" }
2: { Status : 1
 DateFrom : "2018-08-04 00:00" 
 DateTo : "2018-08-11 00:00" }
3: { Status : 1
 DateFrom : "2018-09-01 00:00" 
 DateTo : "2018-09-08 00:00" }
4: { Status : 1
 DateFrom : "2018-09-02 00:00" 
 DateTo : "2018-09-08 00:00" }
5: { Status : 1
 DateFrom : "2018-09-08 00:00" 
 DateTo : "2018-09-15 00:00" }
6: { Status : 1
 DateFrom : "2018-10-01 00:00" 
 DateTo : "2018-10-06 00:00" }
7: { Status : 1
 DateFrom : "2018-10-06 00:00" 
 DateTo : "2018-10-13 00:00" }
```

any one know how can do that please help me for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort()` is the correct method you need to use, however you need to compare the values of the `DateFrom` properties after converting them to `Date` objects, like this:

```
res.sort(function(a, b) {
  var aDate = new Date(a.DateFrom), bDate = new Date(b.DateFrom);
  return aDate - bDate;
});
```

```js
var res = [{
  Status: 1,
  DateFrom: "2018-09-01 00:00",
  DateTo: "2018-09-08 00:00"
}, {
  Status: 1,
  DateFrom: "2018-09-02 00:00",
  DateTo: "2018-09-08 00:00"
}, {
  Status: 1,
  DateFrom: "2018-09-08 00:00",
  DateTo: "2018-09-15 00:00"
}, {
  Status: 1,
  DateFrom: "2018-10-01 00:00",
  DateTo: "2018-10-06 00:00"
}, {
  Status: 1,
  DateFrom: "2018-10-06 00:00",
  DateTo: "2018-10-13 00:00"
}, {
  Status: 1,
  DateFrom: "2018-07-01 00:00",
  DateTo: "2018-07-07 00:00"
}, {
  Status: 1,
  DateFrom: "2018-07-07 00:00",
  DateTo: "2018-07-14 00:00"
}, {
  Status: 1,
  DateFrom: "2018-08-04 00:00",
  DateTo: "2018-08-11 00:00"
}];

res.sort(function(a, b) {
  var aDate = new Date(a.DateFrom), bDate = new Date(b.DateFrom);
  return aDate - bDate;
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Or the oneliner : `res.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.DateFrom) - new Date(b.DateFrom))`

Comment: Very nice - but be aware that it won't work in any version of IE :( That's the only reason I haven't fully adopted arrow functions yet.